# Open link on any page click

Tags: javascript

i need a way to open a specific link  (for example www.google.it)  on ANY mouse left click on the page

So for example, if there is a button called  "home" and the user click on it, it will open two pages   home.htm   and  www.google.it

Is there a way?

I'm trying to use a simple javascript code but it's not working with supersized :)

http://inogroup.it/new/313/slideshow/fade.html

Comment: sorry, i could not add javascript tag :)

Comment: Yes, google.it specifically. Not an ad, certainly no.

Comment: an exact link :) how to do it? :)  don't need for ad :)

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064998/how-to-make-a-link-open-multiple-pages-when-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Just use `window.open`. You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

For example, the code using jQuery would be like this (assuming the link has an id "home"):

```
$("#home").on("click", function() {
    window.open("http://www.google.it");
});
```

And another example not using jQuery but just plain old JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("home").onclick = function() { window.open("http://www.google.it"); }
```

Your link will open on the current tab, and the other url (google.it) will open on a new tab.

Comment: is that code javascript? :)      and, how to add an id for my image with supersized code?  http://inogroup.it/new/313/slideshow/fade.html    Thank you very much!

Comment: That code is JavaScript. I don't know what "supersized code" is (and sorry, I won't follow the link you shared). But if you want to do it for an image, it would be something like this: `<img src="..." onclick="window.open('http://www.google.it');window.location='http://www.google.com'" />`

Comment: i added this       <script type="text/javascript">
$("#home").on("click", function() {
    window.open("http://www.google.it");
});
</script>        but it seems not working? maybe i should add id somewhere... is it not possible to remove the id and make it general for ALL the page? :)

Comment: the problem is that i've something like this   {image : 'http://inogroup.it/new/313/1.gif', title : 'Quiet Chaos by Kitty Gallannaugh', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2010/12/kitty-gallannaugh/'},

Comment: That is some incorrect json code that I don't really know what has to do with the question.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, this isnt a pure javascript solution.. this is jquery.

Comment: Ok, I just edited the solution to add a pure JavaScript alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Alvaro's answer a pure java script solution

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (/* your disabled check here */) {
      // Kill the event
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    // Doing nothing in this method lets the event proceed as normal
  },
  true  // Enable event capturing!
);
```

This answer is built on this previously answered question.
[JavaScript - Hook in some check on all 'click' events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802025/javascript-hook-in-some-check-on-all-click-events)